# Minimize matrix-difference subject to block-diagonal constraints

Tags: matlab, matrix, optimization, linear-algebra

I have a matrix W which is a block diagonal matrix with dimensions 2*4, and each of its two block diagonals is 1*2 vector. I want to find the values of its entries that minimize the difference between the following function: 
( F = BH-AW )
Where:  W is the required block diagonal matrix to be optimized,  B is a 2*2 matrix, H is a given 2*4 matrix, and  A is a 2*2 matrix. A and B are calculated using the functions used in the attached code.
I tried this attached code, but I think it is now in an infinite loop and I don't know what should I do?

```
    %% My code is:

while ((B*H)-(A*W)~=zeros(2,4))
            w1=randn(1,2); 
% generate the first block diagonal vector with dimensions 1*2. The values of each entry of the block diagonal vector maybe not the same.

            w2=randn(1,2); 
% generate the second block diagonal vector with dimensions 1*2.
            W=blkdiag(w1,w2); 
% build the block diagonal matrix that I want to optimize with dimensions 2*4.

            R=sqrtm(W*inv(inv(P)+(H'*inv(eye(2)+D)*H))*W'); 
% R is a 2*2 matrix that will be used to calculate matrix A using the LLL lattice reduction algorithm. The values of P (4*4 matrix), H (2*4 matrix) and D (2*2 matrix) are given. It's clear here that matrix R is a function of W.

            A= LLL(R,3/4); 
% I use here LLL lattice reduction algorithm to obtain 2*2 matrix A which is function of R.

            B=A'*W*P*H'*inv(eye(2)+D+H*P*H'); 
% B is 2*2 matrix which is function of A and W. The values of P (4*4 matrix), H (2*4 matrix) and D (2*2 matrix) are given.

        end
```

Comment: The "function" `F` is 2x4 matrix. In what sense are you trying to minimize `F`? You can potentially minimize its 2-norm, Frobenius norm, sum of the absolute values of the elements, etc.

Comment: I haven't tried to understand the body of your loop, but the loop test `while ((B*H)-(A*W)~=zeros(2,4))` is never going to be satisfied with regular floating point even if you had a formula for the optimal `A` and `B` that achieve that result in exact arithmetic.  You should do something like monitor `norm((B*H)-(A*W))` instead and stop when it gets small enough.

Comment: So, you think that If I use ``` while (norm((B*H)-(A*W))~=0) ``` instead of using ``` while ((B*H)-(A*W)~=zeros(2,4)) ``` this will solve the problem?

Comment: I tried using while (norm((BH)-(AW))~=0), but till now there's not any output and it seems to enter an infinite loop. is there any other way that can optimize matrix W?

Comment: @bg2b is suggesting something like `while norm((B*H)-(A*W))>tol` where `tol` is your tolerance, e.g. `10^-5`.

Comment: I tried this idea, but it doesn't give me the optimal solution as each time I run my code, the result has a different W matrix! I want to find the optimal one!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Numerical operations with floating point numbers are only approximate on a computer (any number is only ever represented with a finite number of bits, which means you cannot exactly represent Pi for example). For more info, see [this link](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html).

Consequently, it is extremely unlikely that the loop you wrote will ever terminate, because the difference between `B*H` and `A*W` will not be exactly zero. Instead, you need to use a **tolerance factor** to decide when you are satisfied with the similarity achieved.

Additionally, as suggested by others in comment, the "distance" between two matrices is typically measured using some sort of norm (e.g. the Frobenius norm). By default, the [`norm`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/norm.html) function in Matlab will give the 2-norm of an input matrix.

In your case, this would give something like:

```matlab
tol = 1e-6;

while norm(B*H-A*W) > tol

    % generate the first block diagonal vector with dimensions 1*2. 
    % The values of each entry of the block diagonal vector maybe not the same.
    w1=randn(1,2); 

    % generate the second block diagonal vector with dimensions 1*2.
    w2=randn(1,2); 

    % build the block diagonal matrix that I want to optimize with dimensions 2*4.
    W=blkdiag(w1,w2); 

    % R is a 2*2 matrix that will be used to calculate matrix A using the LLL lattice reduction algorithm. 
    % The values of P (4*4 matrix), H (2*4 matrix) and D (2*2 matrix) are given. 
    % It's clear here that matrix R is a function of W.
    R=sqrtm(W/(inv(P)+(H'/(eye(2)+D)*H))*W'); 

    % I use here LLL lattice reduction algorithm to obtain 2*2 matrix A which is function of R.
    A= LLL(R,3/4); 

    % B is 2*2 matrix which is function of A and W. The values of P (4*4 matrix), 
    % H (2*4 matrix) and D (2*2 matrix) are given.
    B=A'*W*P*H'/(eye(2)+D+H*P*H'); 

end
```

Note that:

- With regards to the actual algorithm, I am a little bit concerned that your loop never seems to update the value of `W`, but instead updates matrices `A` and `B`. This suggests that your description of the problem might be incorrect or incomplete, but that is beyond the scope of this forum anyway (ask on [Maths.SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/) if you want to know more).
- Using `inv()` directly is discouraged in many cases. This is because the algorithm to compute the inverse of a matrix is less reliable than the algorithm to solve systems of the type `AX=B`. Matlab should give you a warning to use `/` and `\` where possible; I would advise following this recommendation unless you know what you are doing.

Comment: I tried this idea, but it doesn't give me the optimal solution as each time I run my code, the result has a different W matrix! I want to find the optimal one! How can I find it?

Comment: @CassidyTom What makes you think there is a unique "optimal solution"? In any case, that is a different question, which you should post on the Maths forum, with a mathematical description of the problem. This forum is about programming, and my answer is a valid solution in that regard.

Comment: I don't understand how this could be the accepted (correct) answer. You are trying to "find the values of W that minimize the difference between the following function: (F = BH-AW )", yet `W` is updated randomly in each iteration. There is no way this algorithm would converge unless you somehow stumble upon an `W` that satisfies the tolerance condition.

Comment: @Kavka The fact that the algorithm is incorrect has nothing to do with the fact that the original attempt entered an infinite loop. The description of the problem in the OP obviously doesn't match what the code is doing (A and B are updated, instead of W), but given that this is a programming forum, I fixed the code, not the algorithm.

Comment: @Kavka "There is no way this algorithm would converge unless you somehow stumble upon an W that satisfies the tolerance condition." So.. there is a way.